# Is this an efficient way to get data from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to learn, not building anything serious, and trying to learn the most efficient ways of building stuff.

Is this the most efficient way to get data from a database where I have to get multiple data, creating one new function for each field in the database?

api.php

```
<?php
class MyAPI
{
private $mysqli;
protected $db;

public function __construct($db)
{
     $this->db = $db;
}

public function getName($id)
{
    $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM users where id = ?");
    $statement->bind_param('i', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($name);
    $statement->fetch();
    $statement->close();

       return $name;
}
 public function getMail($id)
{
    $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT mail FROM users where id = ?");
    $statement->bind_param('i', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($mail);
    $statement->fetch();
    $statement->close();

       return $mail;
}

}
```

show.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'dbconnection.php';
require_once 'class/api.php';

$api = new MyAPI($db);
$id=1;
echo $api->getName($id);
echo $api->getMail($id);
```

Comment: This question might be better to ask at: [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"